# PyQt5 resizes tkinter window automatically

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt5

I am trying to open a web page using `PyQt5` after a button press in `tkinter` window.

As soon as the new window opens, it resizes (downsizes in this case) the `tkinter` window permanently.

**Minimal code required to reproduce this**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

class Web:
    def __init__(self,url,title='',size=False):
        self.title=title
        self.url=url
        self.size=size

        self.app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.web=QWebEngineView()
        self.web.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.web.load(QUrl(self.url))
        if size:
            self.web.resize(self.size[0],self.size[1])
    
    def open(self):
        self.web.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

def launch():
    web=Web('https://www.example.com')
    web.open()

root=Tk()

button=Button(root,text='open',command=lambda:Thread(target=launch).start())
button.pack(padx=100,pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```

**Images for reference**

*Both the images have the same height.*

[image]
[image]

I would like to know the reason and a way to prevent this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the downsizing in Linux. However Qt complains that the app is not created in the main thread and the link in the webpage is not clickable. Trying to use several GUI toolkits with separate mainloops together is tricky. Maybe try to put you PyQt code in a separate file and run it with `suprocess.Popen` instead.

Comment: @j_4321 Thanks a lot for your suggestions. The `suprocess.Popen` method works without any issue. But if I need to pass on a url to the script then I'd have to pragmatically rewrite that part of the script every time before executing it. As of now, for my use case, I haven't found any noticeable issue with it not being in the main thread and the link does work for me.  Also, if I were to distribute the app as an executable then I might have to do a bit more research to get it working in a similar manner.

Comment: Is there an *actual* reason that makes it necessary to use both tk *and* Qt? Having components of two GUI frameworks working together is rarely a good idea (most of the times it's just a **really bad idea**, and is considered bad practice): they all have their own event loop and there shouldn't be another concurrent one that works in a different way. In any case, you don't need to "programmatically rewrite" to pass the url, just use a command line argument.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your suggestions. I have an app, entirely written with tk but I would like to open a few web pages within the app environment (without using external web browsers), since tk does not have any widget to render web pages, I thought to use Qt for this purpose, web wrappers like `pywebview` have the same issue as they need to run in the main thread, which causes rest of the program to not respond while in use. I would be glad to learn if there is a better approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. `PyQt` changes the dpi awareness which does not happen by default with `tkinter`. Due to which the `tkinter` window resized itself as soon as `PyQt` was launched in the same main loop.

Since I am on a windows machine, using this solved the problem.

```py
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```